# Are curly brackets used in Lua?

Tags: syntax, lua

If curly brackets ('{' and '}') are used in Lua, what are they used for?

Comment: I was curious about adding a simple preprocessor to replace them with the "do/then" and "end" to make it a little less verbose.

Comment: Take a look at token filters and metalua, both referenced frequently in the Lua-L mailing list found at www.lua.org. Both offer ways to modify the language at the abstract syntax tree level, and might be able to do this. A preprocessor would need to do a lot of parsing to get it right.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Table literals.

The table is the central type in Lua, and can be treated as either an associative array (hash table or dictionary) or as an ordinary array. The keys can be values of any Lua type except `nil`, and the elements of a table can hold any value except `nil`.

Array member access is made more efficient than hash key access behind the scenes, but the details don't usually matter. That actually makes handling sparse arrays handy since storage only need be allocated for those cells that contain a value at all.

This does lead to a universal 1-based array idiom that feels a little strange to a C programmer.

For example

```
a = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

creates an array stored in the variable `a` with three elements that (coincidentally) have the same values as their indices. Because the elements are stored at sequential indices beginning with 1, the length of `a` (given by `#a` or `table.getn(a)`) is 3.

Initializing a table with non-integer keys can be done like this:

```
b = { one=1, pi=3.14, ["half pi"]=1.57, [function() return 17 end]=42 }
```

where `b` will have entries named "one", "pi", "half pi", and an anonymous function. Of course, looking up that last element without iterating the table might be tricky unless a copy of that very function is stored in some other variable.

Another place that curly braces appear is really the same semantic meaning, but it is concealed (for a new user of Lua) behind some syntactic sugar. It is common to write functions that take a single argument that should be a table. In that case, calling the function does not require use of parenthesis. This results in code that seems to contain a mix of `()` and `{}` both apparently used as a function call operator.

```
btn = iup.button{title="ok"}
```

is equivalent to

```
btn = iup.button({title="ok"})
```

but is also less hard on the eyes. Incidentally, calling a single-argument function with a literal value also works for string literals.

Answer (score 4):

list/ditionary constructor (i.e. table type constructor).

They are not used for code blocks if that's what you mean.  For that Lua just uses the end keyword to end the block.

[See here](http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Lua.html)

Comment: There are no lists or dictionaries in Lua, but a "table" type which serves as both. So curly brackets are used as a table constructor.

Answer (score 2):

They're used for table literals as you would use in C :

```
t = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

That's the only common case. They're not used for block delimiters. In a lua table, you can put values of different types :

```
t={"foo", 'b', 3}
```

You can also use them as dictionnaries, à la Python :

```
t={name="foo", age=32}
```